Group the navigation links in Drawer in React Native
My drawer navigation has links and all however I want to group the links with just a title like below. How can I achieve this?

Following is my code:

import LinkOne from '@/screens/settings/linkone';
import LinkTwo from '@/screens/settings/linktwo';
import LinkThree from '@/screens/settings/linkthree';

export default function Settings({route, navigation}: any) {

  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      defaultStatus="open"
      
      screenOptions={{
        drawerType: "permanent",
        headerShown: true,
      }}
      >
          
        <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Link 1" 
          component={LinkOne}
          />
        <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Link 2" 
          component={LinkTwo} 
          />
        <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Link 3" 
          component={LinkThree} 
          />
      
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};


See the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent.

I managed to find a workaround. Added a new drawer screen with a DummyComponent and prevented the default click action using listeners.
Remember to define initialRouteName="Link 1" for your Drawer.Navigator
<Drawer.Screen 
  name="Title A" 
  component={DummyComponent}
  options={{
    drawerLabelStyle: { 
      color : 'gray',
      textTransform: 'uppercase'
    }
  }}
  listeners={{
    drawerItemPress: (e) => {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action
    },
  }}
/>

